# Java Process with (C++) childprocess/thread or similar

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, process, signals

My Problem today is:
I need to start a Program (it's a C++ program) from Java. When the Java program stops, the C++ Program needs also to stop and vice versa.

My Ideas:
I need to run the Program in a new Thread. When the thread stops, I can exit the java program. And if the Java program stops, the thread will be killed.

or

I need to run the Program in a new Sub-Process of the Java Process. And receive in the Java Process signals to check if the child process dies.

Does anyone know how I can get this behavior?

Comment: Does it matter that the other program was compiled from C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a shutdown hook in the main Thread, and in this hook you can kill the application, or send an exit signal.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // kill the application here!!!
        killCProgram();
    }
});
```

In the code above, the java application will wait for `killCProgram`.

In truth, if is two process, they are independents.